# Проблема с реализацией интерфейса

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой: по заданию курсовой надо создать интерфейс и реализовать его.

```cs
public interface IDoc
    {
        int SumNakladnaya(int price, int kol);
    }

 class Nakladnaya: Document, IDoc
    {...
 public int SumNakladnaya(int p, int k)
        {
            return p * k;
        }
    }
```

Пытаясь использовать функцию в самой программе, мне выдаёт ошибку "Ошибка   CS0120  Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Nakladnaya.SumNakladnaya(int, int)" требуется ссылка на объект"

```cs
                    N[i] = new Nakladnaya();
                    N[i].SetPrice(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[5, i].Value));
                    N[i].SetKol(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[6, i].Value));

                    int v = Nakladnaya.SumNakladnaya(N[i].GetPrice(), N[i].GetKol());
```

Долго с этим сражался, но никак не могу понять, что именно и где надо исправить, потому что интерфейсы не поддерживают статические методы, а это, как мне кажется - единственный вариант исправления данной ошибки. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: `N[i].SumNakladnaya(...)` PS: Ну и параметры у этого метода, наверное, не нужны, пусть работает с полями класса

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вы правы! Вот, что значит - глаз замылился. Спасибо большое, теперь всё работает. Боже, поверить не могу, что всё так очевидно на самом деле было..

Comment: @DeuKrom, немного не в тему, но на будущее... Лучше не допускайте транслита в идентификаторах.

Comment: @DeuKrom, если проблема решена — оформите решение ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`N[i].SumNakladnaya(...)` PS: Ну и параметры у этого метода, наверное, не нужны, пусть работает с полями класса